# Cmakefiles missing after code coverage execution

Tags: gitlab, lcov, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to generate code coverage report using LCOV in Ubuntu platform. I referred
https://github.com/QianYizhou/gtest-cmake-gcov-example

It is working.

I am giving cmake --build ../application/build --target install in my shell script.

After script execution, I can see that the cmakefiles are generated in the build folder.

```
cd build && make test
cd build && make coverage_TEST_NAME //To check the coverage
```

I did execute above in my build folder and I generated report.

My problem is, I use this in gitlab pipeline. There is no build folder I can see. So I don't know how to do  make coverage_TEST_NAME in my yml file

Generate code generation output in gitlab pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved. Just like in my Ubuntu virtual machine, the application folder was there in my docker image.

I just added a ../application/build command in my yml script, it navigated there.